# definition of finite pointed spaces in Lurie Higher Algebra

Tags: algebraic-topology, higher-category-theory

Let $S$ be the infinity category of spaces. 
In Higher Algebra 1.4.1.4 Lurie defines $S^{fin}$ as the smallest full subcategory of $S$ which contains the final object $*$ and is stable under finite colimits. Is it the case that the objects of $S^{fin}$ are just  Sing X where X is finite sets of points?

Comment: No. This is the quasicategory of finite cell complexes.

Comment: @ZhenLin Okay, yes, that was my first guess. But why is it that?

Comment: "Colimits" here are "homotopy colimits", not ordinary $1$-categorical colimits.

Comment: @Zhen: don't you need retracts of finite complexes or something like that?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan To split an idempotent you need more than finite (co)limits.